How to install the Raspberry Pi desktop interface in Ubuntu server?
The Raspberry Pi desktop for desktop computers is an extremely lightweight operating system.
I want to install a light operating system on a old 64 bit computer. I came across Raspberry Pi desktop, but it is 32 bit, which many programs don't support anymore. The Raspberry Pi desktop interface is a modified version of the LXDE desktop (with a different set of default panels/widgets that improves the user experience).
I want to install LXDE on Ubuntu server, and setup the LXDE to resemble the Raspberry Pi desktop interface. I am sure that it can be done by modifying some configuration files in the home folder.
How to turn the LXDE interface into the Raspberry Pi desktop interface in Ubuntu?

Are you going to self answer this?

Maybe ask the Pi people, I mean developers, to publish a 64 bit version of Raspberry Pi OS for AMD64 chips?

Can't you just install the relevant desktop environment? Presumably, it is open source and available somewhere, so you should be able to install their modified LXDE anywhere, at worst you might need to compile it, right?

No I don't have plans to self answer this. The relevant desktop environment is LXDE + custom panels and widgets, and some modified default settings. I could not find any such configurations in https://github.com/raspberrypi
